# MSCRM 2011 Hiding Tab based on value of statcode field

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, show-hide, state

I want to hide a tab in Quote entity based on value of statecode field of quote entity.

Senario:
If the value is equal to ''3'' tab should be visible, if not tab should be invisible.
You can find my code below but it's not working.

Please help, thanks.

```
   function hideTab(){
var field = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("statecode");    
if (field == null || field.getValue() == null)
    return;
var value = field.getValue();
if(value != "3")
    return;

Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get(tab_9).setVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: `Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get('tab_9').setVisible(false);` Note the quotes. Does this work for you?

Comment: I tried but It doesn't work jasonscript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to read the field value using JavaScript, the field **must** be in the `body` of the crmForm (i.e. not in Header or Footer areas).

Additionally, I would refactor your code like this

```
function hideTab (){
    var field;
    var fieldValue;
    var isHidden = false;

    field = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("statecode");    
    if (field != null && field.getValue() != null){
        fieldValue = field.getValue();
        alert(fieldValue);
        if(value != "3")
            isHidden = true;
    }

    alert(isHidden);
    Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get('tab_9').setVisible(isHidden);
}
```

Notice I've added a couple of `alerts` so that you can check that

1. the function is running
2. the field is found
3. the field value is correct

Comment: Alert says ''False'' and it hides the tab on every situation. I think there is something wrong with getting value of ''statecode''.

Comment: I found this in another answer: `Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_fieldSchemaName").getValue();`

Comment: Now it says ''Unable to get property 'getValue' of undefined or null reference.

Comment: @Eldanar in order to use the `getValue` method the field must be added to the form. Are you sure `statecode` is on the form? Otherwise you need to do a webservice call to get the value

Comment: the `statecode` field must be in the body form, not only in the header or in the footer

Comment: I think i understand the problem. statecode is the technical name of Status field and this field is not a custom field. Yes i see it at the bottom of Quote entity but its non-editable and read-only. Probably we have to do a webservice but i dont know how to do.

Comment: @Eldanar sounds like the `statecode` attr is in the Footer. You can add it to the form body too. You can add additional js to hide this field too if you don't want to see it. If it's not on the form, then you can't get the value without retrieving it from the server

Comment: You guys are right, i have added on the form and it is working now. Thank you guys jasonscript and @Guido.

Answer (score 0):

you can hide the tab by  using any of these:

```
window.parent.Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get(tabindex).setVisible(false);
or
window.parent.Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("tabname").setVisible(false);
```

if this is not working then first check what `window.parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute()` is giving or better log `field` .

see a brief example here:https://mahenderpal.wordpress.com/tag/ms-crm-2011/

if you are sure that satecode is in form then use this to get the `satecode`:

```
window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("statecode");
```

Comment: It says ''Unable to get property 'getValue' of undefined or null reference when i used `Xrm.Page.getAttribute()`

Comment: thanks but i dont have any problem with hiding the tab, the problem is reading statecode field and hide the tab based on the value of it.

Comment: @Eldanar try this:window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("statecode"); to get statecode.

Comment: I think i have to do a webservice to get data of statecode.